# value stream is not a member of Application.this.Status in play framework 2.6.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I was on play framework version 2.4.3 then I upgraded it to play 2.6.0 i am getting a compilation error

```
myproject/app/controllers/Application.scala:146: value stream is not a member of Application.this.Status
[error]     Ok.stream(responseStream).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004)
[error]        ^
```

here is the code which is breaking

```
def prometheusMetrics = Action {
    val responseStream = Concurrent.unicast[Array[Byte]] { channel =>
      val writer = new WriterAdapter(channel)
      TextFormat.write004(writer, CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.metricFamilySamples())
      writer.close()
    }
    Ok.stream(responseStream).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004)
  }
```

how this code works in play 2.6 ?

Comment: You should take a look at the migration guide, it is quite helpful: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/StreamsMigration25#Migrating-streamed-results-(feed,-stream)-(Scala-only)

Comment: Also, it might be easier to first migrate to Play 2.5, and then 2.6 (and then 2.7) instead of jumping straight to 2.6.